# Kivy TextInput horizontal and vertical align (centering text)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

How to center a text horizontally in a TextInput in Kivy?

I have the following screen:
[image: wrong screen]

But I want to centralize my text like this:
[image: right screen]

And this is part of my kv language:

```
        BoxLayout:  
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                markup: True
                text: '[b] Type something... [/b]'
                size_hint: 1, 0.6
                size: self.parent.size[0], 200
                font_size: self.size[0] * 0.1
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 0, 204
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

            TextInput:
                focus: True
```

How can I center my TextInput's text?

Comment: Centering text horizontally is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38421741/1542900

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Afaik, there's no such thing as aligning in the same way as it's in `Label`, however, you can use [`padding`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.padding) to push the position wherever you want. Keep in mind that changing the size of text will affect the centering, therefore you'll need to recalculate on change of size (e.g. when working with multiple devices, sizes, etc).

Or there could be even a workaround, where you could make `TextInput` invisible, use `Label` to fetch touch event to trigger `TextInput` (which would open keyboard) and change `Label`'s text on change of `TextInput`'s text property. You'll lose the possibility to work with cursor this way and you'll need to handle wrapping text.

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    TextInput:
        text: 't'
        font_size: 60
        # left, right
        padding_x:
            [self.center[0] - self._get_text_width(max(self._lines, key=len), self.tab_width, self._label_cached) / 2.0,
            0] if self.text else [self.center[0], 0]
        # top, bottom
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):
    pass
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()
TestApp().run()
```

`self._get_text_width(...)` is obviously a method of a `TextInput`. It's working with the core of the widget so it might be unstable (first example I posted was buggy because of my mistake) ^^

Now if `padding_x`'s values padd from `left` and `right`, you'll need only the left side (the difference is only in using addition and substraction in the right place), so let's do that:

1. get the longest substring in the `TextInput`
2. get its width (because it's not consistent!) via the fancy method
3. substract from `center[0]` coordinate

When we've already centered the X axis, let's go to the Y. `padding_y`'s values are `top` and `bottom`:

1. padd down the half of the widget's `height`
2. get a half of a height of a single line
3. multiply the number by the count of lines that are in `TextInput`
4. substract the number from `self.height / 2.0`
5. bottom is `0`, we don't care about it

Note: `max()` expects some arguments and if there's no `text`, `max()` will raise its voice. We'll shut it with an alternative left padding for `padding_x` using only the center:

```
<padding_x with max> if self.text else [self.center[0], 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. How can I use padding to centralize? I tried it, but, like you sad, I had problems with different sreens sizes and different font size. How can I make it work?

Comment: @Caaarlos added example and explanation ^^

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate your help. I'm working now, when I have time, I will test it. Thank you, again!

Comment: @KeyWeeUser, it worked, but how can I make it work on a TextInput that does not have a initial text? Just a hint text?

Comment: @Caaarlos edited, just a little `if` is needed for `padding_x`, where the `max()` causes the issue.

Comment: using this code, when I have no text, the text_hint and the text input's cursor goes to the left. Can you help me?

Comment: @Caaarlos yes, I forgot to put here the updated code with `self.center[0]` for `x` padding

Comment: How would one do `self.height` when not using kv language, but just `t = TextInput()`?

Answer (score 6):

@pete halign: 'center' plus the padding on y axis only does the job as well

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    TextInput:
        text: 't'
        halign: 'center'
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):
    pass
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()
TestApp().run()
```

Comment: It should be the designated answer

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `halign: "center"` , in your TextInput